# jQuery - Tabbed Content - Open on Selected Tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I've created some tabbed content.  Is there any way for me to decide which tab I want open by changing the URL?  I'm sure I've seen something similar before but can't find it!

I've created a fiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/sW966/**

The default tab is tab 1.  But for example, if the URL was `http://jsfiddle.net/sW966/#tab-2`  the page would load with tab 2 open?

Thanks for any help, struggling a little :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab").click(function () {
        $(".tab").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#tabbed-content .tab-content").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change your JS to:

*Note this wont work in jsfiddle due to the way it works.*

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    if(window.location.hash){
        tabChange($('.tab[href=#'+window.location.hash+']'));
    }

    function tabChange(tab){
        $(".tab").removeClass("active");
        tab.addClass("active");
        $("#tabbed-content .tab-content").hide();
        $(tab.attr("href")).show();        
    }    
    $(".tab").click(function () {
        tabChange($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle code is 
 http://jsfiddle.net/manedeepak08/sW966/1/
you can test 
[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/manedeepak08/sW966/1/show/#tab-3)

Comment: @DeepakMane - the above wont work in jsfiddle as far as Im aware, you cant access `location.hash`

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This works - However, when I use url.com/#tab-2 the page drops down to the tab.  I've used $(".tab").click(function (e) {e.preventDefault(); to combat this when clicking the tabs, just doesn't seem to work when you use a new url to change the tab.  Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to add: `setTimeout(function() {
  if (location.hash) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}, 1);` to your code, not elegant, but a solution

Comment: Appreciate that!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sW966/3/)**

Replace attribute "href" to "name"..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".tab").click(function () {
     $(".tab").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
     $("#tabbed-content .tab-content").hide();
     $($(this).attr("name")).show();
  });
});
```

Good Luck....

Comment: Hi, name works fine but it just gives me the same result as before.  If I change the URL, the default tab still opens?  Thanks

Comment: Hi Pradeep, it's still not working for me?  Using Chrome

Comment: Still no luck - This is the link I'm using - http://fiddle.jshell.net/sW966/3/show/#tab-2  Should this work?